# search for road data using coordinates.?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I have the path data labeled tabel_roads, I want to find the nearest road using coordinates. this is the script I have, but it does not work.

```
                            select id from tabel_roads ORDER BY geom <-> st_makepoint(-6.1688009873927925,106.8256151676178) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: please give me link :)

Comment: btw., in `ST_MakePoint`, `x` is *longitude*, `y` is *latitude* - switch the ordinates!